# difference between use of NOT in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a difference between:

SELECT .... WHERE id NOT IN ( ... some values ... )

and

SELECT .... WHERE NOT id IN ( ... some values ... )

I had problems with the first one if id had null values. In this case the rows with the null values were not considered in the result set but if I did:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id is NULL
```

I got a non empty  result set. Why is this? Is this answer DB engine dependent?

The queries are like:

```
select id, name from mytable where id not IN ('1', '2','3','4', '5', '6', '7') limit 10;
 id | name 
--------+---------+--------+--------+---------
(0 rows)


select id, name from mytable where id is null limit 10;
....
(10 rows)
```

In this case the possible values for the id column are '1', ... , '7', null

Comment: Which database are you using? You've tagged both MySQL and Postgres.

Comment: Postgres, but I wonder if there is a difference between postgres and mysql and other engines.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the MySQL tag then, because there doesn't seem to be any reason to mention that and not any of the dozens of other systems out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Null is difficult to get your head around. Because it doesn't follow boolean logic. One way of looking at it is that it is saying "I do not know" (or in some cases "I do not care'). So to answer your question, "is NULL element of a list like ('1', '2', '3')?" the answer is Null, further if you modify the question to "is NULL element NOT of a list like ('1', '2', '3')?" the answer is still Null. This holds all boolean and most string operators (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e653abcac4d9d9b6ab839c9798a33634)). Safest process, until you get used to it, when in doubt TEST IT, but don't let the result surprise you.

Answer (score 1):

The two are exactly equivalent.  Both return nothing if any of the values are `NULL`.

If any of the values in the `NOT IN` list are `NULL`, then `NOT IN` returns either `FALSE` (if the value is in the list) or `NULL`.

On the other hand, if any of the values in the list are `NULL`, then `IN` returns either `TRUE` or `NULL`.  That is fine.  Negating that produces either `TRUE` or `NULL`.

Comment: This is hard to understand for me... is NULL  element of a list like ('1', '2', '3') ?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga . . . Not of that particular list, but `NULL` is allowed in the set, particularly if there is a subquery.